# Show table on laravel filament resource edit page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I am on laravel filament and I wanted to show a history of the subscription like Shopify show app history, I am able to fetch the subscription on the index page of the subscription resource but I don't know how can I show a history of the subscription on the tabular format on the view page. Below is the screenshot of how Shopify shows its app history to the users.

[image: shopify app history]

[image: Laravel filament subscription history]

I have shown all subscription details like this, and I want a table like Shopify to show an app history when I click on a particular record. Thank you

Comment: You can use Relation manager https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/resources/relation-managers

Comment: Wanted to fetch details from `API`, But don't know how to manage this with relation managers.

Comment: So your subscription and subscription_history not related? not sure wym by API

Comment: You can also use the Table Widget [ https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/dashboard/tables ]

also, you can customize your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I have created a [custom page](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/resources/custom-pages) from filament.

`php artisan make:filament-page SortUsers --resource=UserResource --type=custom`

This command creates two files, one is a class file and the second is a view file. In the class file, I fetched the data with the help of the `getViewData()` function from the stripe and returned that data to the view file. And in the view file, I have shown that data in a tabular format.

Steps:-

Run this command:-
`php artisan make:filament-page SortUsers --resource=UserResource --type=custom`

```
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources\UserResource\Pages;

use App\Filament\Resources\UserResource;
use Filament\Resources\Pages\Page;

class SortUsers extends Page
{
    protected static string $resource = UserResource::class;

    protected static string $view = 'filament.resources.user-resource.pages.sort-users';

    public function getViewData(): array{
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Do a logical code in the `getViewData` function and return data to the view file.

In the `sort-users.blade.php` get the output of the array and print the data

```
<x-filament::page>
   {{ $data }}
</x-filament::page>
```

Comment: What is url to check in browser because in sidebar no link has been created

Comment: Can you explain more about what type of issue you face, I have done nothing to show a sidebar. the filament is managed sidebar itself.